# AWS EC2-LINUX "Network connection refused" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have created AWS environment for my DEV and QA. Both the environments are created using the same CloudFormation template. DEV Environment is up and running. But I am unable to launch the QA Instance due to which our testing stopped.

When I try to login to the QA Machine it says

```
Network connection refused
```

I have checked the security groups opened port 22 on the machine. I have checked the VPC Configurations and NACLS. Everything looks fine.

What might be the issue?

Comment: For your information, I have gone through AWS EC2 Troubleshooting document and got to know that one reason might be the SSH Deamon inside the EC2 instance might have been stopped. Does anyone know how to restart it without accessing the linux machine

Comment: have you tried restarting machine ?

Comment: Wait, are you "unable to launch the QA instance" or are you not able to log in?  Those are two different things.

Comment: When I launch the putty client and pass on my private key the system says network connection refused. In the AWS EC2 Management console, The instance shows running.

Comment: The machine was restarted and I tried accessing with the new public IP. But still the same issue.